# Facebook graph api - not able to get other user activity data done on my post

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using developer.facebook.com to access certain data via graph api from my facebook page which i have created. Example comments like reactions. 
get/v6.0/me?fields=id,name,posts{comments,reactions}

```
"id": "1234",
"name": "XXXX",
"posts": {
"data": [
  {
    "id": "1234_4567",
    "reactions": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1234",
          "name": "XXXX",
          "type": "HAHA"
        }
```

Though i am getting all the information in jason,  only which i have posted , reacted or commented, but i am not able to get any jason output for activity done by any other users.
My friend also reacted and commented on same post but i am not able to get his activity.

2) I am also trying to get likes on the post and getting below error
get/v6.0/me?fields=id,name,posts{likes}

```
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (Post)",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "AF8RQ88df6ohfXHWNHBzLKB"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your app still in dev mode? Then you are only supposed to get such data for people with a role in the app.

Comment: yes it is currently in dev mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Facebook [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/2020-02-03-endpoint-deprecations) that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

like -> reactions.summary(true) 
maybe it works.